# Telegram api escape work but print it in message

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I am using telegram api in Python3.

I am using parse mode as markdownv2. I use the \ character as an escape to type the - characters in the text. I also use escape character for "(" and ")" characters.

While transmitting the message to the telegram, the escape characters I used only for the - characters are also seen in the telegram message.

```
def telegramNotification(message):
    TOKEN = "xxx:AAGrrzwEJ0Pxxxxs6h5pv0tYo9n-4"
    chat_id = -629454
    message = message.replace("-","\\\\-")
    url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={message}&parse_mode=MarkdownV2"
    http = urllib3.PoolManager(timeout=5.0)
    resp = http.request('GET', url)
    respMsg = json.loads(resp.data.decode('utf-8'))
    print(respMsg)
    if respMsg["ok"]:
        print("This is ok")

telegramNotification('test\-for\-now and \(pharantesis\)')
```

Telegram message:

[image: Message show slashes]

I expect not seen \ characters in message

****Tried:****

```
    msg = "test-for-now and (stackoverflow)"

newmsg = msg.replace("-","\\-")\
    .replace("(","\\(") \
    .replace(")","\\)")

print(newmsg)

telegramNotification(newmsg)
```

Print Result:

```
test\-for\-now and \(stackoverflow\)
```

Telegram Result:

[image: msgx]

Comment: Escape character works only with specific character like `\n` else it is a normal character

Comment: i do not use escape characters for python3, telegram need escape characters. **Telegram Says:**  In all other places characters '_', '*', '[', ']', '(', ')', '~', '`', '>', '#', '+', '-', '=', '|', '{', '}', '.', '!' must be escaped with the preceding character '\'.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that in MarkdownV2 mode, every character with ASCII codes between 1 and 126 (which includes a dash) [can be escaped with a backslash](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api):

> Any character with code between 1 and 126 inclusively can be escaped anywhere with a preceding '' character, in which case it is treated as an ordinary character and not a part of the markup. This implies that '' character usually must be escaped with a preceding '' character.

But let's look into what is actually happenning, step by step.

First, you are passing `test\-for\-now and \(pharantesis\)` to the `telegramNotification` function.

Then you replace every dash (`"-"`) with `"\\\\-"` which is actually two backslashes and dash in Python standard notation (unless you use raw strings which is not the case here).

So actually `\\-` passed to query to Telegram API. As per documentation for MarkdownV2 mode, double backslash is interpeted as escaped backslash, so you end with a backslash and a dash: `\-`.

If you want to escape the dash and not the backslash, I think you need less backslashes in your string:

```
message.replace("-","\\-")
```

Comment: Your solution is not work. Added as tried in issue